# Hibernate messages when using @DataJpaTest with SpringBoot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am doing @DataJpaTest on default spring boot settings. When I run the test, hibernate(?) is flooding console with schema creation messages like:

```
Hibernate: alter table ...
Hibernate: alter table ...
Hibernate: alter table ...
Hibernate: alter table ... 
Hibernate: call next value ...
```

And so on. Does anyone knows how to disable this messages? I have logback configuration for test with log level OFF on root logger.

/Annonymous

Comment: Try to set show-sql: false

Comment: Works perfect - I made Darren answer as solution. Thanks both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `@DataJpaTest` by default show SQL output.

```
 * If SQL output should be logged.
 * @return if SQL is logged
 */
@PropertyMapping("spring.jpa.show-sql")
boolean showSql() default true;
```

you can set the showSql=false within the annotation `@DataJpaTest(showSql=false)`